# How to generate getters and setters in eclipse for mutable objects?

Tags: java, eclipse

one of the sonar issue that I recently found was that 
"Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object"

For example ideally Eclipse should generate setter for date like following

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = (Date)billDate.clone();
}
```

How can I force Eclipse to generate code like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates
```

Enable project specific settings

You'll see "Setter Body", Edit:

```
${field} = ${param};
```

The code you need might be written as

```
try {
        ${field} = ${param}.getClass().cast( ${param}.clone() );
} catch( CloneNotSupportedException cnse ){
     // whatever
}
```

I admit that I don't know whether there is a template variable for the parameter class. Investigating...

Comment: I thought that you knew this, according to you question. - Note that this will be the code for all - even where clone is protected or when the parameter isn't an Object. So you'll have to write other forms manually.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. investigating from my side as well :-)

Comment: The variables the template editor offers for "insert variable" is a very poor lot. Nothing like "param_type".